# MySQL modify query to get a specific row

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank,
    userID,
    xpTotal
from users xpTotal, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
WHERE username != '' && bot = 'false'
ORDER BY xpTotal DESC
```

Which results in something like this:

```
rank   |    userID    |  xpTotal 
--------------------------------
  1    |  2934729447  |   52873
  2    |  8523954935  |   33465
  3    |  4576456556  |   13466
  4    |  2341234555  |   04244
  5    |  3453565334  |   02297
```

How can I modify my query to get the rank of say ID `2341234555`? Meaning, in this case, the query would only output the 4th row.

Comment: just add another WHERE for that particular ID

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that wouldnt get the rank then, it would always be rank 1

Comment: @USER You're right, John's answer below also picked up on that.  Bad me for treating the rank like an analytic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your current in a subquery, otherwise if you add it in the condition in the current `WHERE` clause, the rank would always be 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank,
        userID,
        xpTotal
    FROM users xpTotal, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    WHERE username != '' && bot = 'false'
) a
WHERE a.UserID = '2341234555';
```